# facets in elastic 5.5

Tags: database, elasticsearch, facet

I'm trying to build a feceted search with elastic 5.5 (With elastic 2.* I found information on how to do this but in 5.5 I can't)

Not something unusual, store-like items that i want to show hint of the amount if the user will choose to filter using some property. [Image for visualisation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgZRA.png)

Data set example:

```
[
  {
    "id" : "978-0641723445",
    "cat" : ["book","hardcover"],
    "name" : "The Lightning Thief",
    "author" : "Rick Riordan",
    "series_t" : "Percy Jackson and the Olympians",
    "sequence_i" : 1,
    "genre_s" : "fantasy",
    "inStock" : true,
    "price" : 12.50,
    "pages_i" : 384
  }
,
  {
    "id" : "978-1423103349",
    "cat" : ["book","paperback"],
    "name" : "The Sea of Monsters",
    "author" : "Rick Riordan",
    "series_t" : "Percy Jackson and the Olympians",
    "sequence_i" : 2,
    "genre_s" : "fantasy",
    "inStock" : true,
    "price" : 6.49,
    "pages_i" : 304
  }
,
  {
    "id" : "978-1857995879",
    "cat" : ["book","paperback"],
    "name" : "Sophie's World : The Greek Philosophers",
    "author" : "Jostein Gaarder",
    "sequence_i" : 1,
    "genre_s" : "fantasy",
    "inStock" : true,
    "price" : 3.07,
    "pages_i" : 64
  }
,
  {
    "id" : "978-1933988177",
    "cat" : ["book","paperback"],
    "name" : "Lucene in Action, Second Edition",
    "author" : "Michael McCandless",
    "sequence_i" : 1,
    "genre_s" : "IT",
    "inStock" : true,
    "price" : 30.50,
    "pages_i" : 475
  }
]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you searching for this? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup.html

Comment: No, my cluster is up and runnig. I just want to do the aggregation

Comment: Then are you searching for this? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_executing_aggregations.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to use aggs instead of facets. Aggregations are much more powerful than facets.

For example:

```
GET index/_search
{
    "aggs" : {
        "countries" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "country" }
        },
        "types" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "type" }
        }
    }
}
```

Then if a user click on a "facet", just add a filter clause within a bool query (this will update all facet counts) or add a post_filter to just filter the results (does not affect aggregations).

Comment: I can't find any good exmaple for aggs thats aggregate on couple of fields seperetly (I will want to count the results by countries and by type for example)

Answer (score 0):

if the column is text, you will need to use ".keyword" too to handle cases of country names where there are many words ("El Salvador", "United States of America", etc)

```
GET index/_search
{
    "aggs" : {
        "countries" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "country.keyword" }
        }
    }
}
```